# get CPU usage of a VM (linux) using java

Tags: cpu-usage, kvm, libvirt

Is there an API for Java in getting the CPU usage of a VM in KVM? I want to know how I could get the CPU usage using java. Also, does anybody know where I could find the source of virt-manager so I could learn how it gets/computes the CPU usage is displays in Virtual Machine Manager? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try kernel config /proc/config.gz for CONFIG_PARAVIRT_CLOCK and CONFIG_KVM_CLOCK

Comment: I tried going into the proc directory but it doesn't have any config.gz file in it –